# matlab code for data streaming kmeans

Tags: matlab, k-means

I want to have the ability to [stream kmeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_stream_clustering), meaning that after clustering a set of data, I want to add additional data to a cluster or create new clusters, all without having to run over the old data.

I did a lot of searching but wasn't able to find matlab implementation of this code, there were many C source code however. Do anyone know of something like this?

Comment: I'll be the first to ask - what did you try, and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @there is nothing I could try, the only brute force method is for me to write up the implementation by interpreting research papers. Being able to stream kmeans in matlab is my problem, since I currently have to redo kmeans clustering everytime there is new data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'start' parameter of [kmeans](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html).

> Matrix: k-by-p matrix of centroid starting locations. In this case,
>   you can pass in [] for k, and kmeans infers k from the first dimension
>   of the matrix. You can also supply a 3-D array, implying a value for
>   the 'replicates' parameter from the array's third dimension.

Comment: is this the same as data streaming? So what seems to be the case is that I could just put the kmeans results from the previous iteration and put it here. I'll try that out, but I wonder if it really would be this easy considering all the very recent research papers about this.

Comment: I don't know. I have never streamed kmeans... Out of curiosity, do you have a link to a good article explaining how to stream kmeans in case I find the time to skimm through?